# Getting No Response When Calling WebAPI Post with application/json header

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I've got a very simple WebAPI controller (all system defaults) and when I do a post to it, the fact that it has Content-Type: application/json makes the post (from fiddler) hang (not return).

My headers are as follows:

```
Content-Length: 2
Content-Type: application/json
```

and the post body is simply

```
[]
```

My WebAPI controller just looks like this:

```
namespace WebAPI.rest
{
public class SendGridController : ApiController
{

    public HttpResponseMessage Post()
    {
        try
        {
            HttpContent requestContent = Request.Content;
            string json = requestContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.Trim();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

    }
```

When I make the same post (with fiddler) to http://respondto.it/ it returns no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be an old version of webapi.  Once I updated to webapi2, the problem went away.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running under ASP.NET the the `.Result` is probably not a wise idea.  I ran your code under self-host and it worked fine.

Try this,

```
public class SendGridController : ApiController
{

public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
{
    try
    {
        HttpContent requestContent = Request.Content;
        string json = await requestContent.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

}
```

}